# Access Report not Filtering when Others Are

Tags: ms-access, filter, report

I have a form which allows the user to edit the properties of a filter via some combo boxes, then open a report. The report is opened with

```
DoCmd.OpenReport rptName, acViewReport, , whereClause, acWindowNormal
'whereClause = "Building = '005'" for instance
```

Some reports open fine, by which I mean they populate with the filtered info. Others, however, even though they are based off the same in-house template, IGNORE the filter all together and display a report based on ALL data (not the filtered data).

Why would a report ignore the filter? When I edit the reports in design mode after opening them with the form:

```
Working Report              |       Non Working Report
Filter: Building = '005'    |       Filter:  
Filter On Load: No          |      Filter On Load: No
```

**What could be causing the non-working report to not register the filter argument?** There's no On Load VBA, nor any VBA, in these reports (except for an Export to PDF and a close button which is copy-paste for each report).

**EDIT**
Should have checked before, this happens regardless of whether or not the query driving the report is empty (ie the filter is never applied to some reports, regardless of blankness)

Not sure if the code will help, but:

```
Private Sub btnOpenSummary_Click()
  If IsNull(Me.cboSummary) Then
      MsgBox "Please select a building for the SUMMARY report."
      Exit Sub
  End If
  strCrit = "Building = '" & Me.cboSummary & "'"
  MsgBox strCrit
  survArray = getSurveyArray()
  For Each Survey In survArray
      DoCmd.OpenReport Survey, acViewReport, , strCrit, acWindowNormal
  Next Survey
  DoCmd.OpenReport "Total Summary", acViewReport, , , , Me.cboSummary
End Sub
```

Comment: are you sure they're all getting opened using the path with the filter in the code, and that the whereClause variable is not empty?

Comment: I'm using a For Each loop on an array containing the report names; the whereClause is set outside of the loop; in other words Yes. I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "using the path".

Comment: Just to clarify, for testing purposes you're opening each report with the same filter?

Comment: Yes; it's a makeshift way of creating a summary. It's seperate reports (for things like Bathrooms, Bedrooms, Offices, etc) which are filtered by Building. All reports are opened with the same filter, ie displaying "All summaries for Building X". It's not for testing purposes. It's the way the client has asked for the reports to be displayed.

Comment: Check the `Filter On` property of the reports in question - it should be 'Yes', obviously.  You may need to manually set the `Filter` property to `Building = '005'`, then set the `Filter On` property to `Yes`.

Comment: I just meant, are you sure the report isn't being opened on some other code path, bypassing the filter setting?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. It's a fairly short code, and the code is identical between reports; yet some reports do not apply the filter.

Comment: @MaxVernon, I don't know where you see a `Filter On`, but the `Filter On Load` makes no difference. `Filter: Building='005'; Filter On Load: Yes` still produces NO filter, even when simply clicking in the Nav pane to open the report.

Comment: The `FilterOn` property is not available in design view, but you can check its value by adding a `MsgBox Me.FilterOn` to the `Report_Load()` sub in the report VB - also you can look at the ribbon and see if the 'Toggle Filter' button is selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a direct solution, but rather a workaround which should almost certainly work. Instead of applying filtering to the report, dynamically change the report data source by passing the where clause as a parameter.

To open the report use:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport rptName, acViewReport, , , acWindowNormal, whereClause
```

Note that the `whereClause` string is being passed as the `OpenArgs` parameter.

Then in the report VB:

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)
On Error GoTo ReportOpenError

    If Not(IsNull(Me.OpenArgs)) Then
        Me.RecordSource = Replace(Me.RecordSource,";"," WHERE " & Me.OpenArgs & ";")
    End If

    Exit Sub

ReportOpenError:
    MsgBox "Unable to open the specified report"
    Cancel = 1
End Sub
```

This solution assumes the report `RecordSource` is defined as a semicolon terminated SQL query (not a query name) **and** the record source does not already contain any `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, etc., clauses. In those cases, it may be easier to redefine the query from scratch.

Comment: This solution is much more reliable.  I normally do a variation on this by setting the `Me.RecordSource = 'XXX'` in the Report_Open Event, thereby not relying on the report's `RecordSource` property at all.

Comment: I actually do this in some of my forms, using OpenArgs as the where clause. Problem with this is that my reports are filled using a defined query, not a query in the RecordSource itself. `RecordSource: [myQuery]`

Comment: @StuckAtWork: Well you could keep the user defined queries by replacing the form Record Source to `SELECT * FROM [myQuery];`: then adding a `WHERE` clause later would work and allow you to design / test your queries in the query Designer. Not that any of this is relevant now that you have a solution, but just FYI

Answer (score 2):

My fault.. there was code which had for some reason been linefed all the way down the code page and out of view. There was an On Open which played with the Control Source. It ended up being useless (as the control source only needed to be set once, not every time) but it was disabling the filter for some reason. Anybody else who may have this problem:

**Make sure the control source is not being altered in your VBA for the report.**

Thanks to those that helped, sorry my information was wrong.

My OnOpen code:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel as Integer)
   Me.RecordSource = Me.Name
End Sub
```

It takes the name of the report, which corresponds to a name of a query, and puts it as the recordsource. (I have about 40 reports done this way, so it's dependent on names to make it fast to duplicate for different items).

Removing this made it work perfectly using Access 2010. Not sure if this was a problem specific to my setup or what, but, this change directly fixed it.

Comment: Ha, I was just about to propose an answer which achieves the filtering *by* modifying the control source. Since I have already started writing, I will post it up for others to read.

Comment: The OnOpen was literally changing the control source from "qryName" to "qryName".. and somehow disabled the filter abilities. I suppose when Access sees "source isn't the same" it assumes "the filter could not POSSIBLY be relevant anymore; discard it". Silly if you ask me.

Comment: I normally put an invisible label on the Report that says "RECORDSOURCE SET IN CODE", and make the background of the label RED so you can never miss it!  Making the label invisible makes it so the report doesn't show the label when in Preview/Print mode, but does show it when in Design mode.

Answer (score 0):

This problem may also occur when a report is copied and re-purposed. I had a report that was working fine then made a copy of it and was no longer able to filter it.

Perhaps there is a glitch in Access that causes it to ignore the filter when the report is copied under certain circumstances.

Solution: Instead of copying and re-naming the report, try creating a new report, linking the data source, and copying the fields back into place. If you are dealing with a new report, try re-creating it.